Oobabooga Leetcode Question: Longest Palindromic Substring solution works in custom test case but not when submitted
I am getting back on the Leetcode grind in preparation for rejoining the workforce as a SDE. I am pretty certain I got this question right, and according to my custom test case it does pass. Why does it not behave as expected when submitted?
class Solution:
    def longestPalindrome(self, s: str, checked = set()) -> str:
        print(s, self.isPalindrome(s))
        if len(s) == 1 or self.isPalindrome(s):
            return s
    
        if s in checked:
            print(s, checked)
            return s[0] #shortest palindrome in s
        checked.add(s)
    
        lp2 = self.longestPalindrome(s[:-1], checked)
        lp1 = self.longestPalindrome(s[1:], checked)
        print()
    
        if len(lp1) > len(lp2):
            return lp1
        return lp2
    
    def isPalindrome(self, s:str) -> str:
        i=0
        j=len(s)-1
        while i<j:
            if s[i]!=s[j]:
                return False
            i=i+1
            j=j-1
        return True



Please keep in mind that this is not a help desk, and thus we do not write answers here that "find the bug". We require a specific question - which will come out of your best attempt to understand and locate a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the specific part of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely expect something), and don't understand why.

The default argument for checked is always the same set instance, so results from previous test cases can affect later ones. You could instead set it to None by default and initialize when necessary.
def longestPalindrome(self, s: str, checked = None) -> str:
    if checked is None:
        checked = set()

With this change, you will get the correct answers, but exceed the time limit for later cases. To resolve this, pass two indexes to represent a substring to the longestPalindrome method instead of passing a whole string and performing linear slicing each time. Moreover, it is only necessary to check the two outermost characters at each recursive call.
To solve this even more efficiently, apply Manacher's algorithm for a solution in O(N).

You can also check out my answer here for a bottom up dynamic programming solution in Python.

Please read Why should I help close "bad" questions that I think are valid, instead of helping the OP with an answer?, and do not post answers for duplicate questions (i.e.: questions about common duplicate issues), especially not ones that are clearly not asking the question as well (i.e.: OP has not done the necessary work to extract a MRE and find the bug in order to ask about it). The duplicate for this issue is one of the most frequently used in the Python tag.
